# What are some backbone.js naming conventions?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, conventions

I know it is not that important, but I am just curious as to how people name their models / collections / views / router functions.

Comment: A great resource for Backbone naming conventions can be found here: http://ricostacruz.com/backbone-patterns/#conventions

Answer (score 3):

That all depends on what the model, collection, etc represents and how they are used structurally.

I typically give my models a generic name and then suffix all others with their constructor type

Ex:

```
//  model
var Animal = Backbone.Model.extend({});....
//  collection
var AnimalCollection = Backbone.Collection......
// view
AnimalView = Backbone.View.extend(){})....
```

Now you can create a new animal view simply by passing it it's model and other people who read your code can easily understand what the model represents.

```
var view = new AnimalView({ model: new Animal({name: 'Tiger'});
```

Of course, you can always suffix your models with the word **Model** as well, but I think it speaks well enough without it since a model represents a single flat object with properties not some sort of view or collection of objects.

Comment: i agree it is readable, but i don't like typing collection all that mutch :) so why not use Animal,  Animals and AnimalView? i keep View mostly because a model / collection can have more than 1 view, AnimalListView AnimalDetailView etc etc, but the collection tends to be 1 big pool, if i have more than 1 collection of the same object (which is quite often) they are usually contained in a parent model, and then they get proper names,  like Animals and myPets for example.

Comment: I don't like use the a plural version because it is so easy to add an extra **s** to a model or leave one out on a collection, which leads to obnoxious bugs. You could always abbreviate Collection to Col as well. :P

Answer (score 3):

- All collection names plural somehow, like people/doors/doorlist.
- Classes begin with capital, instances use camel/underscore.
- Never include the word model, collection, etc. in name.
- Put all in a hash called c, m, r, v which has benefit of iteration.

```js
var c.People = Backbone.Collection.extend();
var c.people = new c.People();

var m.Person = Backbone.Model.extend();
var m.person = new m.Person();
```